# Iteration with lambda in racket?

Tags: lambda, scheme, lisp, racket

This is probably a simple question, but I cannot seem to figure it out.
In the example below, I want to create a function `list-of-obj` that recursively creates a list of items.

Example:

```
> (list-of-obj 'a 5)
'(a a a a a)
```

The code:

```
#lang racket
(define (list-of-obj obj n)
  (letrec ((helper
           (lambda (obj n result)
             (if (> n 0)
               (helper obj (- n 1) (cons obj result))
               result))))
      helper obj n 0))
```

This, however results in output of `0`. Any pointers? I'm new to racket/scheme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most idiomatic solution in Racket would be:

```
(make-list 5 'a)
=> '(a a a a a)
```

That is, you should not reinvent the wheel if a built-in function does what you want. But if you need to write it from scratch, this should do the trick:

```
(define (list-of-obj obj n)
  (letrec ((helper
            (lambda (obj n result)
              (if (> n 0)
                  (helper obj (- n 1) (cons obj result))
                  result))))
    (helper obj n '())))
```

There were two problems with your code:

- The call to `helper` must be surrounded by `()`, because that's how you call a procedure in Scheme.
- The initial value for the accumulator must be an empty list given that we're building a list as the output, not a `0` as you had it.